# How to divide an image into overlapping sub-blocks by sliding window?

Tags: image, matlab

How to divide an image into **overlapping sub-blocks by sliding window**?

Comment: `im2col(im, [M N], 'sliding')` or `blockproc`

Comment: Respected Sir,
Thank you for your suggestion.
I am trying to use:
     I3 = blockproc(I,[100 100],fun);
but not able to know what code should i write for "fun" so as to divide the image into overlapping blocks. Please suggest me.
With Regards
Rashi

Comment: Sir, I had also tried using:
I2=blockproc(a, [1 1], @(bs)disp(bs.data),'BorderSize', [1 1 ]);
Taking "a" as in matrix form 
                   or
I2=blockproc(I, [1 1], @(bs)disp(bs.data),'BorderSize', [1 1 ]);
(simply by reading an image using "imread"; and then writing the below code)

figure;
imshow(a);
figure;
imshow(I2);

In both cases, results are visible in command window but images are not coming? What to do next. Also, how to vary size of sliding window?Please suggest.
Thank you.